# how do I delete an Eclipse project when I've already deleted the folder and contents?

Tags: eclipse

How do I fully delete an Eclipse project when I've already deleted the folder and contents?  I want to do this so that I can reuse the project name.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try removing directly the project within your workspace, within:

```
<workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\
```

as mentioned in "[Where in an Eclipse workspace is the list of projects stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251116/where-in-an-eclipse-workspace-is-the-list-of-projects-stored)"

Comment: This didn't work initially for me. It was *still* listed in the "open project list" even after I deleted the folder from the metadata folder. **However!** When I tried opening the project it now worked (albeit with one error). I was then able to remove the project cleanly.

Comment: @altCognito interesting: what version of Eclipse did you used?

Comment: 3.7.2 -- maybe I missed something when I did it, not sure why it happened that way.

Comment: Per @Otzen answer, hit F5 in the package explorer after doing this, and then Eclipse will prompt you to remove the project you just manually deleted. That's when it will actually become available again for re-import/re-creation.

Answer (score 9):

In my case the project was completely removed yet still referenced in Eclipse. Thing is, the file holding the Working Sets configuration was the culprit. What I did was:

1. Shut down Eclipse
2. Open `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/workingsets.xml`
3. Find the faulty `<item>` tag and remove it
4. Start Eclipse

Answer (score 4):

Don't have rep to comment directly on @VonC's answer yet. But here is how it worked for me.

1. removed the projects from 
   `<workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\projects\`
   As suggested above
2. Try to open each project, clicking "ok" to all th errors
   Now it seams it is gone, but if I try to import a new project with same name Eclipse claims they are still there.
3. in the project explorer press 'F5' to refresh. N ow eclipse realises the project is gone, and asks if it should remove the project from workspace, after accepting the project is now gone.

Maybe step 2 can be skipped, I have not tried.

My eclipse:
Luna Release (4.4.0)